# Using transform with raphael sets

Tags: javascript, raphael

Hi everyone I cant figure out how to move a Raphael set . For the docs I've read you can use transform to resize and reposition the element. But regardless of what string arguments I put into the function it doesnt seem to change even a slight bit. Can anyone help me reposition and rescale this beatiful chair.

```
seat.push(shapeA,shapeB);
seat.transform("t100,100r45t-100,0");;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ra5qou5/2/)

thanks

Comment: Sorry for the URL but there seemed to be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the 'seat' variable, and initialised it as a set (should this be set?). eg

```
var seat = paper.set();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ra5qou5/3/)